I can't sign in with my Apple ID after transferring a copy of my data using Time Machine imac
Problem:
After transferring Ventura 13.6.7 system and files from MacBook 16 2019 to iMac 2017, I can't log into my Apple ID like any other, always like in the video.
If you create a new user in the transferred system, then everything is ok, he will be able to log in to any Apple ID, but the user is new and my desktop is not there (if it is possible to transfer the desktop of the old user to the new one, write how)
What I've done:
Safe mode doesn't help (it gives an error when logging in to Apple ID: The operation cannot be completed. Error AASignInErrors -8004), VPN doesn't help, changing the username doesn't help, renaming the folder doesn't help. help, replacing the name of the old user's folder with the new user's folder does not help (the system does not boot), commands in the terminal do not help, changing the name of the root folders for users simply leads to an eternal password loading at login.
I need exactly the transferred user with his desktop, if it is possible to somehow transfer it to a new created user so that everything works, I’m waiting for ideas.
Video information: https://youtu.be/Il3qWGrsA8E
After the transfer, the imac shows that I have already signed in to the Apple ID, but there is no synchronization with iCloud and this PC is not on the iCloud website.
If you click sign out of Apple ID and sign in again, it asks for a code,sign in I cannot — there is no error or warning. I click sign in button and the sign in button appears again.  If you go to appstore, the situation is similar.

The problem is solved. You need to go to the folder: user/library (hidden folder)/Keychains. In it, delete or move somewhere everything from a folder like A56E6A70-668F******************** (folder with your current profile data) After that, restart your computer and go to your Apple ID, the Mac will create your data in this folder again and everything will work. Perhaps after this you will have to restart the PC again. Also, if problems arise in the Appstore, you need to switch to another buyer there (if there are several profiles in the system, then there will be a choice) and then back and then everything will work there too.
